# Windows 8 Remote display driver model

Tags: driver, wdk

I'm trying to port the current XPDM Mirror Driver to Windows 8.
Microsoft disables Mirror Drivers completely under Windows 8, but on MSDN it says

> A remote display driver model that is based on the mirror driver architecture can also run starting with Windows 8. For more information, see Remote Display Drivers.

and on the remote display drivers page, it says:

> A remote display driver is based on the Windows 2000 Mirror Driver model and is used to render the desktop in a remote session.

However, I could find any more information for "remote display driver" on the website, except [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh974665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh974667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link on MSDN. The only information I have is that it is based on Win2K mirror driver model, but I don't know what I should do to make it Windows 8 compatible.

I tried to port the XPDM mirror driver code base into Visual Studio 2012, and I used the same inf file. The code can compile and deploy successfully on Windows 8, but the display driver is not loaded by kernel.
The display driver is named accdrv.dll, and the miniport driver is mirror.sys. When debugging the kernel, only the mirror.sys is loaded.

Is there a place where I can find some information on "remote display drivers"? so I can continue the work on it?

Comment: See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/23511281/252770