# Windows MIrror Driver Remote Display Driver VNC server windows 8

Tags: windows, driver, remote-desktop, vnc

I am working on a driver for a remote desktop server. Something like UltraVNC(in house protocol).

First of I see that mirror drivers are not supported on windows 8.
Only subset of DDI as a remote display driver.

1)
Does that mean I need to implement Remote Display Driver for windows 8?

2)Starting of with mirror driver and only adding the DDI specified here enough to have Remote Display Driver run on windows 8 (Will it install no windows 8)? It says that remote display driver is a subset of mirror driver.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh974665(v=vs.85).aspx

3) Are there any any any examples? It looks like the mirror driver example is no where to be found ?
**UPDATE :** (on wdk 7.1) I found these examples.

4) I looked at Utlra VNC server source and It looks like they only have drivers up to Windows 7.  However VNC SERVER still supports windows 8(for that it just does GDI stuff on user level to get the image update). So they have not implemented it. 
There is a Remote Desktop Protocol Driver. Can that be used ?

5) what is the best place to start ?
Is this windows' way to limit remote desktop server implementation so that it is harder to compete with RDP.

6) 
if implementing windows 8 implementing the DDIs necessary to have remote desktop driver is not enough to run it on windows. 
Is the api below only way to do it on windows 8. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: have you had any success with your driver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 8, there is a "Desktop Duplication API". With this API, it seems that you do not need to develop a driver anymore. Doc is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The "Remote Display Drivers" documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh974665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a bit mysterious...

Comment: Yeah That is also what I ended up using. Thanks. I also see that most vnc sever implementations are also using this on Win 8.

Comment: Can Desktop Duplication API be invoked from a service and capture lock & logon screens as well?