# What is the new API that repalces mirror drivers starting in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, accessibility

I've been hearing a lot about how starting with Windows 8 there would be a new API that replaces mirror drivers.  AFAIK, mirror drivers are the only way for an AT application to read text output by drawing APIs such as GDI+ (in particular non-standard controls that don't use any accessibility APIs like UIA or MSAA).

So I did some research and found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which confirms the rumor but doesn't give much information about what's next.  I e-mailed the address it said to contact, but received no response (not even an automatic "thank you for e-mailing Microsoft" message), so I'm not sure where else to look.

So I searched on here and found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937335/windows-mirror-driver-remote-display-driver-vnc-server-windows-8), which said there's a "desktop duplication" API available now; but the documentation that guy provided didn't seem to say anything about accessibility, but more geared toward people developing remote desktop apps - which is really cool but probably not what I was looking for... or was it? (lol)

Thanks in advance. :)